# Partitioning with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot

Ok, so the other day decided to recover my win 7 to factory settings. But, when loading for the first time win 7 opens two pages than error, without even letting me complete the recovery process. Long story short didn't have a win 7 recovery disk so i search for a resolution without the CD. Called Microsoft and Gateway, they both told me that I need spend 100$ toward a new recovery Cd. Than I made the decision to download Ubuntu 12.10 on usb and boot and install. Did so and made a partion of 500-215. After install was able to access win 7 recovery in unbuntu start up menu. Reinstalled win 7 without saving files and docs, it was my only option that worked(but where saved with ubuntu instalation). Ok,so my questions are, both on win 7 and my ubuntu they only display 500gig hdd when I am suppose to have 750 hdd, is it ok that they store in same device and what happened to missing storage?

Help? I'm tired of searching

Comment: They *both* display a 500G hard drive?  That sounds... unlikely.
What I would normally expect would be that each OS can see only part of the hard drive (though Ubuntu should be able to access the Windows filesystem as long as Windows is shut down rather than hibernated).  The two filesystems should total to slightly less than the total size of the hard drive (as Ubuntu will have assigned some of the drive to swap space).

Comment: How big does the BIOS report the drive to be? What make/model of drive is it (many utilities will tell you this, as will a screw driver)?

Answer (score 0):

When installing Ubuntu you have either partitioned your 125~ partition in a format(swap) or you have deleted a partition but have not created one.

Solution #1:

1. Go to Control Panel > Administrative Tool > Computer Management > Disk Management(Sidebar)
2. Below you will see the lost partition in RAW. Delete the partition and create new volume.
3. Far I know you can not recover any data from an unallocated space or swap. Search a bit more if you want to recover the data that you have in the 125~ GB partition.

Solution #2:

1. Use the Ubuntu installation disk to check and create partitions.